# JAX-WS Form Authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws, form-authentication

I have a web service developed with JAX-WS and deployed to a Tomcat server. In the file web.xml I configured Form Authentication but I can't authenticate my client. Is it possibile to use Form Authentication to authenticate a JAX-WS client? All works if I use Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Surely that would not be possible as form authentication interactively prompts for a user name and password which a web service client cannot fulfill.